# ¿Porque al ingresar otra identificacion y comprobarlas no lo lee?

Tags: java, array, poo, netbeans, bucle-for

Buenos dias tengo un problema y es que tengo una ArrayList donde esta nombre, edad, identificacion, etc y de hay quiero con la identificacion corrobar la busqueda de esta para saber si la persona existe o no pero cuando ingreso una identificacion y la comparo son iguales me sale error al ingresar mas de dos datos de la array, en el ejemplo se aclara un poco mas, esto es un ejercicio facil pero no entiendo el error ayuda porfavor gracias

```
     public class AutoMovilesMejorado  {

  ArrayList<Cliente> listaCliente = new ArrayList();


     private void ingresarCliente() throws IOException{   //aqui ingresan los datos
    System.out.println("Ingrese los datos separados por '&':(Nombre, Edad, Identificacion, Presupuesto)");
    String texto = br.readLine();
    String [] dato = texto.split("&");
    String nombre = dato[0];
    int edad = Integer.parseInt(dato[1]);
    int identificacion = Integer.parseInt(dato[2]);
    double presupuesto = Double.parseDouble(dato[3]);
    Cliente clienteNuevo = new Cliente(nombre,edad,identificacion,presupuesto, false);
    if (edad >= 18 ) {
            if (ExisteCliente(clienteNuevo)) {
              System.out.println("Identificacion repetida");  
            } else{
                listaCliente.add(clienteNuevo);
                System.out.println("Usuario Ingresado Correctamente " + "\n" + listaCliente);
            }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Debe ser mayor de edad");
    }
 }
 
 private boolean ExisteCliente(Cliente cliente){   //esto es para verificar que no se repitan identificaciones
     boolean existe = false;
     for(int i=0;i<listaCliente.size();i++){
         if(listaCliente.get(i).identificacion == cliente.identificacion){
             existe = true;
             break;
         }
     }
     return existe; 
 }

   private void busquedaIdentificaciones() throws IOException{   //aqui es el problema
    System.out.println("Ingrese la identificacion");
    int busquedaIdentificacion = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < listaCliente.size(); i++) {
        if (listaCliente.get(i).getIdentificacion()==busquedaIdentificacion){   //listas.contains(busquedaIdentificacion) no me srivio
            desplegarMenu2();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Usuario no encontrado... ");
            busquedaIdentificaciones();
        }
      }
    }
}
```

[image: Aqui esta los datos de la ArrayList]

[image: Aqui la verificacion del las identificaciones]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola veo dos situaciones a corregir:

1 - el For recorre toda la lista, aun después de encontrar el id buscado, por ese motivo, se muestra nuevamente el mensaje "usuario no encontrado" aun cuando ya se encontró.

2- El **else** dentro del **for** hace que solo encuentre el cliente si está en la primera posición de la lista, si no está en esa posición llama nuevamente al método e i vale cero **(i = 0)** nuevamente.

Basado en lo que veo en tu código se puede.

1- Sacar el **else** fuera del bucle ( lo que esta dentro del **else**).

2- Terminar la ejecución del bucle si se encuentra el cliente buscado.

3- La ejecución de lo que esta dentro del **else** debe estar condicionada a si se encontró o no el cliente buscado. ( usar una variable booleana para esto).

ejemplo: para salir del bucle uso la variable booleana, se puede usar break, pero si se encuentra el cliente buscado hay que establecer el valor correspondiente para evitar la ejecución de la llamada recursiva.

```
     boolean flag = false;

 for (int i = 0; !flag && i < listaCliente.size(); i++) {

     if (listaCliente.get(i).getIdentificacion() == bi){   //listas.contains(busquedaIdentificacion) no me srivio
         flag = true;
         //desplegarMenu2();
         System.out.println("encontrado "+ listaCliente.get(i));
         System.out.println(".... desplegar menu");
     }
 }
 if(!flag) {
     System.out.println("Usuario no encontrado... ");
     busquedaIdentificaciones( );
```

**Nota:** *hay métodos que no se que hacen como desplegarMenú2(), lo que puede condicionar la respuesta.*

Comment: gracias bro este el metodo bandera para controlar indicadores, verdad?

Comment: Este método usa la variable bandera (flag) para indicarle al bucle for que ya encontró lo que buscaba (no se ejecuta la proxima interacion) y evitar que llame nuevamente al método  (con el if). Usar una variable flag es  útil en varios escenarios (muy de C). Saludos.